# MATLAB: Symbolic Expression, Integral of Inverse Fourier Transform

Tags: matlab, expression, integral

I have the following script:

```
clear all; close all;

syms t w

% I seek the Fourier Transform of following f 
f = (heaviside(t+1)-heaviside(t-1))*1 ;
L = 10;

h = ezplot(f,[-L,L]) % plot function of problem
set(h, 'Color','r','LineWidth',4)     
grid on

% seek Fourier Transform fw
fw = int(f * exp(-j * w * t),t,-L,L) 
fw_s = simplify(fw,'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true);
fw = fw_s
%fw = (2 * sin(w))/w ;this is the result of Fourier Transform

%inverse Fourier Transform ft
ft = (1/(2*pi)) * int(fw * exp(j * w * t),w,-L,L)
ft_s = simplify(ft,'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true);
ft = ft_s
```

Matlab answer is as follows:

```
%ft = (5734161139222659*int((exp(t*w*i)*sin(w))/w, w == -10..10))/18014398509481984
```

How to force the Matlab answer to be `f = (heaviside(t+1)-heaviside(t-1))*1` as shown in the problem. I know the build in function `ifourier(fw,w,t)`. But for the pedagogic purpose, I would like to solve by using the original formula.

Comment: Better use `(1/(2*sym(pi)))` in your code, then you get a fully symbolic solution for ft: `ft= int((2*exp(t*w*i)*sin(w))/w, w == -10..10)/(2*pi)`

Comment: % inverse Fourier by built in 
iF = ifourier(fw,w,t)
iF = simplify(iF)
subplot(3,1,2)
h = ezplot(iF,[-L,L]) % plot function of problem
set(h, 'Color','r','LineWidth',4)     
grid on

Comment: By using built in function ifourier, we can solve the problem. Can we reach the same results by using the original formula ft = (1/(2*sym(pi))) * int(fw * exp(j * w * t),w,-L,L)

Comment: I don't understand your comments. Isn't that what you already wrote in your question?

Comment: I am sorry. Not easy to use this editor. Your answer to use (1/(2*sym(pi))) , can not solve the problem. Only by using  iF = ifourier(fw,w,t); iF = simplify(iF) can solve the problem, i.e iF = (heaviside(t+1)-heaviside(t-1))*1. It means your answer can not return to (heaviside(t+1)-heaviside(t-1))*1

Comment: I know using `(1/(2*sym(pi)))` does not solve the problem, that's why I just wrote a comment. Doing so you get a fully symbolic evaluation instead of a numeric (slightly inaccurate) one.

Comment: Ok. I appreciate your help. Thanks a lot, Daniel. Best regards.